# Useless Wireless Network Interfaces Wifi Is not working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

When I type my command in ubuntu it is showing me something like this.

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

br-6e37f0ffedf9  no wireless extensions.

vethc10412d  no wireless extensions.

docker_gwbridge  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point:         Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enp1s0f1  no wireless extensions.
```

What are these useless network interfaces and how to remove them from PC

My Wifi is not working.

May be because of all this. Could anyone tell the solution for it.

Comment: Show the output of `rfkill list all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not "useless" interface, they are just interfaces that are not WLAN interfaces. Use `ip link` to get more information about them.

You Wifi not working has nothing to do with it. Deleting them will disrupt whatever things you are doing with them (i.e. the Docker).

To debug the real problem (Wifi not working), find out the vendor and product id for your wifi hardware (`lspci -nn` or `lsusb`), google in form `xxxx:yyyy` to see if you need special drivers, or if the hardware is maybe too new to be supported, and look into `dmesg` for errors or suspicious messages.